# How to deploy msi into Kubernetes in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, windows-installer

I'm new to cloud computing, could anyone please tell is there a way to deploy msi to Kubernetes in GCP

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Kubernetes is based upon Linux. MSI (Microsoft Installer) is an application installer for Windows desktop and server operating systems.

You cannot install a Windows application on Kubernetes in Google Cloud.

There are implementations of Kubernetes on Windows and Windows containers for Kubernetes by other vendors, but neither support MSI application installation.